# Handling Ajax Request Symfony

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, controller

I am trying to perform an ajax post request but I can't handle the form.

Ajax :

```
function ft_postFormation(e) {
e.preventDefault();
data = $('form[name=appbundle_formation_post]').serialize();


$.post({
  url: ROOT_DIR + "api/back_office/post_formation",
  data: data,
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + $.cookie("token"));
  }
}).done(function (e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

}
});

controller :

```
    public function postFormationAction(Request $request)
{
    $formation = new Formation;
    $form = $this->createForm(FormationForm::class, $formation);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        //handling the form
    }
}
```

}

I don't know if I serialize the data correctly or if I do not handle the form correctly. I read this solution everywhere but I am obviously missing something.

I receive the data within the controller (as a string). I also tried to serialize the form with $.serializeArray() but i could not handle the form either.

In all cases $form->getData says the form is correcly created but not filled with the datas received.

Comment: Checked your error-log? The above code would generate an error because the first line in your controlleraction should be "$formation = new Formation();" instead of "$formation = new Formation;"

Comment: @Blablaenzo Thanks but this seems not to be the solution. My version does not trigger any errors. I've added the fix you advise but it does not change anything. $form->getData() still retrieve the form but all the params are empty.

Comment: I've also noticed that `$_POST` is empty, but I can retrieve the data manually with a `$request->getContent();`

Comment: @Blablaenzo `$formation = new Formation;` is [perfectly valid](https://3v4l.org/MmM4I) PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the problem.

The header was wrong. If you use the serialize() Jquery function, the good header is not `dataType:json` but `dataType:x-www-form-urlencoded`. Then, the form is correctly add to the Request object and the form can be handled with `$form->handleRequest($form)`.